# SlashCommandBuilder numberoption cannot access the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

im trying to make a bot that asks for a number of a day (position of an array), and gives back that position, but right now when the user gives the options, in terminal i have an error saying it cant read the properties

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('dia')
        .setDescription('Te doy una entrada del diario')
        .addNumberOption(option =>
            option.setName('numero')
            .setDescription('El numero de dia que quieres')),

        
    async execute(interaction) {
        const dias = ["aqui va lo del dia 1", 
        "aqui va lo del dia 2", 
        "aqui va lo del dia 3)", 
        "aqui va lo del dia 4!!!"];
        const dia = interaction.option.setnumber('numero')
        let diaelegido = dias[dia]
        await interaction.reply(diaelegido);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're calling `<CommandInteractionOptionsResolver>#setnumber` as its not a valid method nor does it make logical sense in the context of attempting to **get** a value.

Consider the following:

```js
const dia = parseInt(interaction.options.get('numero').value);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver